# Optional arguments in nested functions in Python

Tags: python, function

Is it possible for one function to take as an argument the name of one of the optional arguments of a second function then call the second function with the optional argument set to the value of some variable in the first function?

Code (that obviously doesn't work)

```
def foo(a=1,b=2,c=3):
    d = a + b + c
    return d

def bar(variable):
    z = get_user_input()
    e = foo(variable = z)
    return e

print(bar(a))
```

The desired result is for bar to call foo(a=z) and print whatever z+2+3 is. Of course Python doesn't know what (a) is here. My guess is that I can somehow reference the list of arguments of foo() , but I am stumped as to how you might do that.

Comment: Do you mean to call `bar` with the name of the variable as a string: `print(bar('a'))`?  Your code currently would raise an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try the code snippet below

```
def foo(a=1,b=2,c=3):
    d = a + b + c
    return d

def bar(variable: str):
    z = int(input())
    e = foo(**{variable: z})
    return e

# variable name should be defined as string
print(bar("a"))
```

The `**` parses all arbitrary arguments on dict, in this case is `a`. Be careful tho, as if passing wrong variable name (differ from `a`, `b` or `c`) will result raising error.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!